# Socket connection won't close?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to write a simple server program that prints the data sent to it, or quits if the data is "quit", "exit", or "stop":

```
HOST = ""
PORT = 37720

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen(1)

while(1):
    conn, addr = server.accept()

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break

    inData, inUrl = json.loads(data)

    if inData == "quit" or inData == "exit" or inData == "stop":
        print("Quitting")
        conn.close()
        break
    else:
        conn.send("Received")
        print(inData)
```

It does what I expect, except that when I try to run the server again once it's quit, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./s", line 14, in <module>
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I assume this means the connection wasn't closed. How can I close it to prevent this? I tried the `conn.close()`, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: As a side note, your code does _not_ actually work. [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). There is no reason to believe that each buffer you get back from `conn.recv` will be a single message; it could be half a message, or six separate messages. It may work in simple testing on localhost, but fail 90% of the time when you deploy it for real (or, worse, fail 1% of the time, just enough to make it useless but not enough to debug it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set SO_REUSEADDR flag.

```
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```